# Solar2D add dependency for yookassa Java heap space error

Tags: java, android, solar2d

I am trying to create a native android plugin for Solar 2D.
When I add the dependency "implementation 'ru.yoomoney.sdk.kassa.payments:yookassa-android-sdk:6.5.6'" to the build.gradle of the plugin module, an error appears when building the project - AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}. And some file (java_pid6992.hprof) is pulled into the project, which weighs 700 MB. I can't understand, what that file is. Also, i tried to add the same dependency into a clean android project(not built from Solar), this file was not pulled and it worked fine. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2000m in gradle.properties file.